# Does ASP.NET MVC app auto-restart itself on AccessViolationException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-violation

I am working on MVC web app for .NET 4.5.1 using C# and I am using one external dll library. It seems that this library occasionally throws AccessViolationException.

I tried to catch the exception with

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
```

attribute and restart the app with

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

inside catch block.
This works somewhat well but sometimes this exception bypass try block and crash.

Do IIS handles crashes and automatically recover the app from this exception by restarting or is there something I need do?

Comment: IIS should be recovering from the fault and recycling and spinning the site back up. Make sure you are using a machinekey defined in your web.config to limit end-user problems when this occurs.

Comment: As for me you need to find why that external libs fails and try to avoid such situation, as restarting application pool is very unfriendly for WebApp users, as it will cause sessions lost\lags due to app domain restarting

Answer (score 1):

unchecked exceptions generally don't cause the appdomain to unload or the app pool to cycle.  If you're getting unchecked exceptions you may consider using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to catch and log the exceptions so you can see why they are occurring in the first place.

It would be a pretty horrible thing to have your appdomain unload periodically to "handle exceptions", I would recommend trying to figure out why they are occurring in the first place.

Comment: Corrupted state exceptions are not typical unchecked exceptions that can be ignored, as they can corrupt state of application pool process, and Microsoft doesn't recommend executing your application with corrupted state.

Answer (score 1):

"Do IIS handles crashes and automatically recover the app from this exception by restarting or is there something I need do?"

You should always avoid crashes to maintain user experience and avoid your app being hacked.
@cobolstinks Elmah suggestion will only provide stacktrace if it is available which won't help.

An AccessViolationException is associated with unmanaged code and your third party library appears to be the source of the issue, however you need to attach a debugger on the server to watch for this issue and capture a dump when it occurs.

You should install DebugDiag on the server and complete a Crash-Hang-Analysis report.

Make sure you get the latest version: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42933

This will provide a report when the crash occurs and give you far more insight into your issue than Elmah could.

Comment: How would getting the stacktrace not help?  If nothing else he/she can take that back to the library owner for further diagnosis or can submit it in a bug report.

Comment: Agreed, the Elmah captured stacktrace may provide some context of the error if, it bubbles up as anticipated. It may not though and even if it did, it would not provide the detailed application state information that would be presented in the Crash Hang Analysis.  The vendor is surely going to ask what is the state of your app when the error occurs.